# What is causing JS closure variable to be exposed?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a closure I am using to set and retrieve state on an object that several methods will need.

Unfortunately I am encountering some strange behavior. In some situations I want to modify the returned information from the closure while still keeping the variables in the closure in their intended state. In other words I don't want to use the set method of the closure, I simply want to retrieve the object, make a short temporary modification, and let the closure maintain its previous state for any other methods that might need information from it.

This however is not working and my temporary changes are causing the closure object to change despite not using the set method. I wholly admit there are scope level issues I am not understanding. Here is the code:

```
<script>

 var closureTest= {
     filterState: (function () {
         var filterObject = {
             'model': 'ford',
             'year': '2010'

         };

         return {

             setFilterObject: function (input) {
                     filterObject.model = input;
             },

             getFilterObject: function () {
                 return filterObject;
             }

         };
     })()

 };
    //lets retrieve the default values
    var resultsToModify = closureTest.filterState.getFilterObject();
    //now lets attempt to change the model for a one time use
    resultsToModify.model = 'chevy';
    //now lets grab the object again (assuming it will return ford and 
    //2010 because we didn't use the setFilterObject method to change the object 
    var defaultClosureAgain = closureTest.filterState.getFilterObject();
    //expected would show model type as chevy
    console.log('resultsToModify: ',resultsToModify);
    //but why does this show chevy too? 
    //The setFilterObject was never used to modify the object? what am I missing?
    console.log('defaultClosureAgain: ',defaultClosureAgain);

</script>
```

Comment: You're mutating the same object.  You need to explicitly make a copy.

Comment: Best method for doing this? There seems to be many with various pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the getter and setter method outside the function will cause the

exposure of function variables. In your code...

```
  return {

         setFilterObject: function (input) {
                 filterObject.model = input;
         },

         getFilterObject: function () {
             return filterObject;
         }

     };
```

Comment: If you wanted to work on an object then first make a copy of the Object then work on it..

Comment: Is there anyway to not return the getter and setter methods or would that defeat the purpose of the closure?

Comment: Yeah ! you are using IIFE function here which is not at all ok.You don't need to create ` filterState ` as IIFE.. and thus don't need to return setter and getter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal change to your code - returning a copy of `filterObject`. This will allow you to make changes to the copy without affecting the original. The original should only ever be exposed in your `set` API which is (from what I can gather) the only way you intend to mutate that object.

```js
var closureTest= {
     filterState: (function () {
         var filterObject = {
             'model': 'ford',
             'year': '2010'

         };

         return {

             setFilterObject: function (input) {
                     filterObject.model = input;
             },

             getFilterObject: function () {
                 return Object.assign({}, filterObject);
// ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  copy filterObject
             }

         };
     })()

 };
    //lets retrieve the default values
    var resultsToModify = closureTest.filterState.getFilterObject();
    //now lets attempt to change the model for a one time use
    resultsToModify.model = 'chevy';
    //now lets grab the object again (assuming it will return ford and 
    //2010 because we didn't use the setFilterObject method to change the object 
    var defaultClosureAgain = closureTest.filterState.getFilterObject();
    //expected would show model type as chevy
    console.log('resultsToModify: ',resultsToModify);
    //but why does this show chevy too? 
    //The setFilterObject was never used to modify the object? what am I missing?
    console.log('defaultClosureAgain: ',defaultClosureAgain);
```

Note `Object.assign` is ES6+ only. You will need to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or transpiler for full browser support.

I will add that the paradigm you are playing with here doesn't have much real world application, there are most likely better ways to achieve whatever the "end goal" is, if there is one. If you are just playing around to learn, however, that's always a good thing!

Comment: Unfortunately this is real world. I have greatly simplified the code here. I need to constantly check the potentially changing state of an object to help properly construct an API request. I felt a closure would allow me to methodically update and check the state without constantly looking for data attributes or other things that are determining the object value. Perhaps I abandon the "temporary change" and simply make the change using the real setter and simply make a reset method or something for the limited times this particular element needs to change.

Comment: @absentx it sounds like in that case you don't need to modify the object you are inspecting to make the API request. If you do need to modify it for the API request or you simply want it to be protected, you can always return a cloned copy as I've posted above. A closure simply provides a private scope where you can declare variables that are inaccessible by the outer program ... but in this case you are caching the return value of an immediately invoked function - thereby not making use of this principle. (ctd)

Comment: ...By using an immediately invoked function, you are never "resetting" the enclosed variable. You are simply defining a static object with two methods that can easily expose a mutable object. It would be possible to restructure your code more to achieve the desired result in a cleaner way than cloning the object, cloning is simply the path of least resistance.

Comment: I would like to restructure without cloning if possible. Any direction you could provide on how to get and set this object while not unintentionally exposing would be appreciated. It appears that I am not in fact closing over anything, but as you have stated I am simply exposing a mutable object. Most of this project is written in object literals and I continue to struggle to achieve what I want with this pattern.